# Sonar Maven plugin is failing because of a newer maven assembler plugin, how can I get the new plugin to pass properties correctly?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, maven-assembly-plugin, sonarqube-scan, sonar-maven-plugin

Had to update our maven assembler version to 1.1.8 from 1.1.6. It's the only change that happened and now Sonar Maven Plugin is throwing this exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar 
    (default) on project ReconCoverage: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String ->
```

Plugins:

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.7</version>

<groupId>com.CORPNAME.raptor.build</groupId>
<artifactId>assembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.1.8</version>
```

I have been looking into this for about a week, upgrading to this assembler version is required. No other teams are experiencing this issue from the upgrade because they are using Sonar through jenkins. I'm using the maven plugin because our project has many modules, and it structures the coverage results to match it.

I have looked through sonar's code and it seems to be happening in sonar.batch.bootstrap.userproperties. I'm guessing this is happening when the sonar properties are being passed in, items like: sonar.language, sonar.java.coveragePlugin, sonar.host.url, etc. etc.

Example of Coverage Properties:

```
<sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
<sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
<sonar.host.url>http://corp.sonar.url/</sonar.host.url>
<sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@sonardb.corp.com:0000:sonardb</sonar.jdbc.url>
<sonar.jdbc.username>username</sonar.jdbc.username>
<sonar.jdbc.password>password</sonar.jdbc.password>
<sonar.jdbc.driver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracelDriver</sonar.jdbc.driver>
```

According to sonar's code, it normally takes properties through a Map. And it throws this exception when one of those strings is an array list.  Is there anyway to configure my properties so that the new maven assembler will pass these values correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a workaround for this problem. I decided to not go the route of running Java 7 and then 8 to build the coverage report(check previous answers and comments). I'm sure that would work, but since none of our dev or CI machines had Java 8 environments set up, I tried a different route.

I was initially building the sonar report at the end of a `mvn clean install` through a module `CoverageModule`(which as the last module to build). The 1.1.8 java assembler version was throwing a fit when it built the project, and then ran the analysis.

I kept the module so that during a normal build, it would still run my `ant task plugin` to merge all of our module's Jacoco reports. I removed the `sonar-maven-plugin` from that module's pom and put it in the Project's aggregator module(parent of all modules). After running a full `mvn clean install`, I can run a `mvn sonar:sonar` and there appears to be no conflict with the new assembler version, and the old sonar version I was using.

Answer (score 1):

We have implemented a workaround in version 3.1.1 to circumvent buggy plugins injecting non string properties:
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MSONAR-145

To use it just update you pom.xml to use:

```
<groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.1.1</version>
```

Comment: Java version 7 is not compatible with this plugin. Unable to upgrade that at this time. Is there a version that includes that but works for version 51?

Comment: No, we don't support Java 7. Note that you may be able to build you project with Java 7 (mvn clean package) and then run SonarQube analysis with Java 8 (mvn sonar:sonar). Another option is to use Maven toolchains.